# Two or more data types in declaration specifiers error

Tags: c

I am pretty new to C.

I am getting this error:

> incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’

Even when I fix the code based on the answers to include `<stdlib.h>`, I still get:

> two or more data types in declaration specifiers

When trying to do this:

```
struct tnode
{
    int data;
    struct tnode * left;
    struct tnode * right;
}

struct tnode * talloc(int data){
    struct tnode * newTnode;
    newTnode = (struct tnode *) malloc (sizeof(struct tnode));
    newTnode->data = data;
    newTnode->left = NULL;
    newTnode->right = NULL;
    return newTnode;
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Ok, not fair to move the goalposts after people have already (correctly) answered your first question. Now those answers mentioning `stdlib.h` look like they're answering a different question.

Comment: Modified the question so that all the earlier answers weren't invalidated. Might be a good idea to keep that in mind for later, @SuperString.

Comment: And now this question managed to get to the top of the Google results. Bad form changing this question part way through.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You have to put `;` behind the `struct` declaration:

```
struct tnode
{
    int data;

    struct tnode * left;
    struct tnode * right;
}; // <-- here
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer.  The missing ; makes the compiler think that are trying to declare a variable named struct of type struct tnode.

Answer (score 6):

Your original error was because you were attempting to use `malloc` without including `stdlib.h`.

Your new error (which really should have been a separate question since you've now invalidated all the other answers to date) is because you're missing a semicolon character at the end of the `struct` definition.

This code compiles fine (albeit without a `main`):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tnode
{
    int data;

    struct tnode * left;
    struct tnode * right;
};

struct tnode * talloc(int data){
    struct tnode * newTnode;
    newTnode = (struct tnode *) malloc (sizeof(struct tnode));
    newTnode -> data = data;
    newTnode -> left = NULL;
    newTnode -> right = NULL;
    return newTnode;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

"Implicit declaration" means that you're trying to use a function that hasn't been formally declared.

You probably forgot: `#include <stdlib.h>` which includes the function declaration for `malloc`.

Comment: actually its a different error

Comment: Implicit declaration means you went ahead and used a function without letting the compiler know about it ahead of time. So the compiler assumes the function returns an int (it's just making a guess). But malloc actually returns void*, so the assumption and the reality conflict.

Comment: @SuperString: No fair.  It was the correct answer to your original question.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the appropriate header file included?

That is, is there a line at the top of your file that says

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have included the header file that contains the definition for malloc():

```
#include "stdlib.h"
```