# Memory allocation of global structure

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management

```
struct ponto *ps = malloc( sizeof(struct ponto) * colunas * linhas );
```

I had this declared on my main(). However I want it to be globally accessible to all functions. I believe this is made with realloc and declaring this as null or something on the start of the file. Is this correct?

```
struct ponto *ps = null;
```

and then, when I know the size that I need for the struct of arrays:

```
ps = realloc (ps, sizeof(struct ponto) * colunas * linhas);
```

But this doesn't seem to work hehe. Any tips?

Comment: How did you find out that it doesn't work? Calling `realloc` on null is equivalent to `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making `ps` globally visible requires that it is a global variable. You probably also need to do this for the number of columns and lines.

```
struct ponto *ps;
int colunas, linhas;

int main()
{
    colunas = /* whatever */;
    linhas  = /* whatever */;
    ps = malloc(sizeof(struct ponto) * colunas * linhas);
    /* do other stuff */
}
```

Now `ps` is visible to all functions in the source file and through it, they can access the memory it points to.

If you have multiple source files, you'll have to tell them about `ps` in a header file which declares it

```
struct ponto { /* whatever */ };  /* define the struct in the header */
extern struct ponto *ps;
extern int colunas, linhas;
```

`realloc` performs an entirely different operation, it resizes the buffer `ps` points to. `null` does not exist in standard C.

Comment: "two or more data types in declaration specifiers" when I declare struct ponto *ps; Why is this?

Comment: @Queops, did you put a semicolon (`;`) after the declaration of `struct ponto`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098973/two-or-more-data-types-in-declaration-specifiers-error

Comment: I meant, did you include a `;` after the declaration of the *type* `struct ponto`? (Not the variable `ps`.)

Comment: @Queops, I believe your original question has been answered now. Please accept an answer and post a new question when you need more help.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is really just the scope of the variable, you can do this:

```
struct ponto *ps = NULL;
...
int main()
{
    ps = malloc( sizeof(struct ponto) * colunas * linhas );
    ...
}
```

Comment: The explicit `NULL` is not necessary.

Comment: Also `sizeof *ps` would be nicer than `sizeof(struct ponto)`.