# Double declaration c++

Tags: c++, oop

So I have some code in couple of files:
cells.cpp:

```
#include "cells.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char convertIntChar (int symbolNumber)
{
    char charR;
    switch (symbolNumber)
    {
    case 0:
        charR='0';
        break;
// lust of case code here
    case 63:
        charR='\\';
        break;
    }
    return charR;
}

class cell
{
public:
    int iPosition;
    char chPosition;
    cell ()
    {
        static int i = -1;
        i++;
        chPosition=convertIntChar (i);
        iPosition=i;
        cout << " " << iPosition;  //two lines of code to test 
        cout << " " << chPosition; //constructor
    }
protected:
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "cells.h"
#include "pointer.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    createPointer();
    cell cells[64];
    return 0;
}
```

And comeplytly a cells.h

```
#ifndef CELLS_H_INCLUDED
#define CELLS_H_INCLUDED
#pragma once
class cell
char convertIntChar(int symbolNumber);
#endif // CELLS_H_INCLUDED
```

There I have an erros that sounds like 
//filepath\|5|error: two or more data types in declaration of 'convertIntChar'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 7 seconds) ===|
What can it be. Sorry for noob question anyway.

Comment: "// lust of case code here" - You need to get out more!!!

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098973/two-or-more-data-types-in-declaration-specifiers-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this forward declaration needs a semi-colon:

```
class cell;
//        ^
```

Second, you cannot use a forward declaration here. `main.cpp` needs to see the `cell` class definition. So you should put the definition in `cells.h`. For example:

`cells.h`:

```
#ifndef CELLS_H_INCLUDED
#define CELLS_H_INCLUDED
class cell
{
public:
    int iPosition;
    char chPosition;
    cell ();
};

char convertIntChar(int symbolNumber);

#endif
```

`cells.cpp`:

```
#include "cells.h"
#include <iostream>

char convertIntChar (int symbolNumber)
{
    char charR;
    // as before
    return charR;
}


cell::cell ()
{
    static int i = -1;
    i++;
    chPosition=convertIntChar (i);
    iPosition=i;
    std::cout << " " << iPosition;  //two lines of code to test 
    std::cout << " " << chPosition; //constructor
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks but how to make the cell class from main.cpp, it was anounced in cells.h already, yeah? I'm corrected the ; and there couple of new errors: F:\code\bytecode\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
main.cpp|10|error: elements of array 'cell cells [64]' have incomplete type|
main.cpp|10|error: storage size of 'cells' isn't known|
main.cpp|10|warning: unused variable 'cells' [-Wunused-variable]|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 1 warnings (0 minutes, 8 seconds) ===|

Comment: @user2513649 as I said, put the `cell` class definition in `cells.h`, instead of the forward declaration.

Comment: @user2513649 I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You have `class cell` in the cpp file which should go into the .h file.

Then in cells.h you are missing a `;` after `class cell`.

Insterad of the forward declaration in cell.h, put the class there.